# Global Section Functor exactness for Precosheaves

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors

Is the global sections functor for precosheaves fully exact?
Or just right exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precosheaves are just presheaves valued in the opposite category. Limits and colimits of presheaves are computed pointwise, so taking sections over any open (in particular, taking global sections) is exact, and in fact preserves all limits and colimits.